# How to camelize ActiveRecord attributes to JSON respond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, rabl

Somebody have an idea?

I have tried to find this option in [Rabl Gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), but my searches have been unsuccessful. I think this is quite a common action and look forward to an early reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize) supports camlize out of the box, which you should be able to call on any string.

```
"active_model".camelize                # => "ActiveModel"
"active_model".camelize(:lower)        # => "activeModel"
```

See the link for complete documentation.